# Why is servlet deployed to Elastic beanstalk returning empty xml file?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, servlets

I have deployded my servlet to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I'm calling the servlet from client as a http post request with xml file as payload (using stream). The servlet should respond with an xml file as payload. From servlet I'm receiving responsecode 200 but the xml file is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Find my client and servlet code below.

Client code:

```
public class TaxWebClient {

    static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        //Takes file path (input file), url and savedir (directory to save output file) as arguments
        String filePath = args[0];
        String uploadUrl = args[1];
        String saveDir = args[2];
        File uploadFile = new File(filePath);
        //
        //File uploadFile = new File(TaxWebClient.class.getResource(filePath).toURI());        

        System.out.println("File to upload: " + filePath);

        HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        //InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            //Creates a HTTP connection
            URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
            httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //Set timeout (10 and 15 sec.)
            //httpConn.setConnectTimeout(10000);  
            //httpConn.setReadTimeout(15000);

            //Set output & request type 
            httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");        

            //Set headers
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");

            //Sets file name as a HTTP header
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("fileName", uploadFile.getName());

            //Opens output stream of the HTTP connection for writing data
            outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();

            //Opens input stream of the file for reading data
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

            //Loads file from filePath (arg0) when running as JAR file else JAR file won't work
            //inputStream = TaxWebClient.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);

            //Writing data to servlet (outputstream)              
            byte[] bufferInput = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];         
            int bytesRead = -1;

            System.out.println("Start writing data...");

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bufferInput)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bufferInput, 0, bytesRead);              
            }

            System.out.println("Data was send to servlet.");

        } catch (IOException ioe) {         
            System.out.println("Error:" + ioe.getMessage()); 
            ioe.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }           
        }        

        //**RESPONSE**
        //************       
        //Always check HTTP response code from server
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();      

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            System.out.println("Server's response: " + responseCode);

            InputStream inputStreamFromServlet = null;
            //ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStreamFromServlet = null;
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStreamFromServlet = null;
            //OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriterFromServlet = null;

            //String xmlContentFromServlet = null;

            try {
                //****Getting xml file from response**** 

                //Making output filename from input filename
                String fileNameInputWithOutExtension = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(uploadFile.getName());
                String fileNameOutput = fileNameInputWithOutExtension + "TaxOutput.xml";                                

                File saveFile = new File(saveDir + fileNameOutput);

                //Opens input stream of the response for reading data
                inputStreamFromServlet = httpConn.getInputStream();                       

                //Opens output stream for writing bytes 
                //byteOutputStreamFromServlet = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                //Opens an output stream for writing file
                fileOutputStreamFromServlet = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);

                //Turns bytes based stream into character based writer
                //outputStreamWriterFromServlet = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(saveFile), "UTF-8");

                //Writes response from servlet (bites) to byte object - the approach is used because the byte object can be used in more situations 
                byte[] bufferOutput = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int bytesReadOutput = -1;
                System.out.println("Receiving data...");

                //Writes file from input stream
                while ((bytesReadOutput = inputStreamFromServlet.read(bufferOutput)) != -1) {
                    fileOutputStreamFromServlet.write(bufferOutput, 0, bytesReadOutput);
                }           

                System.out.println("Data received.");            

                System.out.println("File written to: " + saveFile.getAbsolutePath());

            } catch (IOException ioe) {         
                System.out.println("Error:" + ioe.getMessage()); 
                ioe.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                if (fileOutputStreamFromServlet != null) {
                    fileOutputStreamFromServlet.close();
                }
                if (inputStreamFromServlet != null) {
                    inputStreamFromServlet.close();
                }
                /*
                if (byteOutputStreamFromServlet != null) {
                    byteOutputStreamFromServlet.close();
                }
                if (outputStreamWriterFromServlet != null) {
                    outputStreamWriterFromServlet.close();
                }
                */              
            }       
        } else {
            System.out.println("Server returned non-OK code: " + responseCode);
        }        
    }
}
```

Servlet code:

```
public class TaxIncomeCalcServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;    

    //Do required initialization of servlet
    public void init() throws ServletException {        

    }   

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //Gets file name from HTTP header and makes new name for output file
        String fileNameInput = request.getHeader("fileName");       

        //Prints out all header values for test purpose
        System.out.println("===== Begin headers =====");
        Enumeration<String> names = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = names.nextElement();
            System.out.println(headerName + " = " + request.getHeader(headerName));        
        }
        System.out.println("===== End headers =====\n");

        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            //Opens input stream of the request for reading data
            inputStream = request.getInputStream();

            //Opens an output stream for writing file
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileNameInput);

            byte[] bufferInput = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            System.out.println("Receiving data...");

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bufferInput)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bufferInput, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            System.out.println("Data received.");

        } catch (IOException ioe) {         
            System.out.println("Error:" + ioe.getMessage()); 
            ioe.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }           
        }       

        //*****Using file from client in server side calculation*****       
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStreamFromCalc = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String outputXml = "";

        //Using xml input file from request as input to the tax calculation which makes a output xml string
        try {
            try {


                //doing some business calculations resulting in document


                XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions();               
                xmlOptions.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                xmlOptions.setUseDefaultNamespace();
                xmlOptions.setSavePrettyPrint();
                xmlOptions.setSaveOuter();         

                //Saving to output stream to implement xml declaration
                document.save(outputStreamFromCalc, xmlOptions);
                outputStreamFromCalc.close();

                //Making string from output stream
                outputXml = new String(outputStreamFromCalc.toByteArray());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (XmlException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        

        //**RESPONSE**
        //************ 
        //Opens an output stream for writing file
        ServletOutputStream outputStreamOutput = null;               
        //Opens an input stream for reading data
        InputStream inputStreamOutput = null;            

        try {

            //Converts from string variable to inputstream
            inputStreamOutput = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputXml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));           

            outputStreamOutput = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType("application/xml");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileNameInput);                 

            byte[] bufferOutput = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesReadOutput = -1;
            System.out.println("Sending xml to client...");

            while ((bytesReadOutput = inputStreamOutput.read(bufferOutput)) != -1) {
                outputStreamOutput.write(bufferOutput, 0, bytesReadOutput);
            }                   

            System.out.println("Data received.");

        } catch (IOException ioe) {         
            System.out.println("Error:" + ioe.getMessage()); 
            ioe.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (outputStreamOutput != null) {
                outputStreamOutput.close();
            }
            if (inputStreamOutput != null) {
                inputStreamOutput.close();
            }           
        }       
    }

    //Ensures that POST method, and not browser default GET method, is used or else failure 405
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    //Do required destroy of servlet
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```